# Moving to UK,I will be going as dependent visa.How to approach an employer for a job?

Tags: united-kingdom, dependent-visa

I'm 27 Years old.Working as team leader(PHP/Wordpress Developer)for an UAE-based company in India.Me,my wife and son(3 year old)all are planning to make the move to London next September. She is going to pursue her's Master Degree there.

I will be going as student dependent.I want to know that, is there any good opportunity for web developer(PHP developer).Do they employment preference to non-native speakers?

Could you please suggest me how to approach an employer for a job as dependent.

Comment: Will you have the right to work on the visa you'll be there on? Only that'll make a huge difference to the process you'll need to follow

Comment: @Gagravarr Yeah I have rights to work there as full time emp.

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date CV covering your skills, education and experience?

Comment: Yes.I have package of portfolio and skill sets.but my worry is employment preference to non-native speakers.is there any good opportunity for web developer(PHP developer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fair sized market in the UK for developers and the largest market is in London. Not being a native speaker should not really affect your job prospects provided that you can still speak and write English reasonably well. In interviews you will probably get a coding test along with a verbal test and most companies look at these results together when deciding on if they should hire you.

In terms of how to approach employers, you can either ask friends to submit your CV to the HR departments of their companies or you can sign up with recruitment agents. Other options are [Stack Overflow Career Boards](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) or similar job boards. If there are specific companies you want to work for, check their websites to see if they are  recruiting.

Also, you need to make sure you definitely have the right to work there. And before you start employment with any company [must ask](https://www.gov.uk/check-job-applicant-right-to-work) to see your passport, visa, and other supporting documents.

Comment: Before starting work with any UK company in the UK, they are [legally obliged to verify your right to work](https://www.gov.uk/check-job-applicant-right-to-work), and take copies of the documents proving it